# Browser is not displaying php output or Errors

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu 12.04. I am able to work with MySQL through Command prompt and User Interface, but when I try to execute a PHP script which includes HTML and MySQL statements, the browser is not displaying the script output and no errors are shown.

Comment: Do you have error-reporting turned on? In your php config file change the error_reporting to E_all and restart Apache.

Comment: Can you post your php script on http://paste.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP errors are not showing in browser only page goes blank](http://askubuntu.com/questions/887612/php-errors-are-not-showing-in-browser-only-page-goes-blank)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution [dan08](https://askubuntu.com/users/158892/dan08) provided, may I know if you have write/execute privilege to the default /var/www directory? Try saving a sample file to that directory.

Run your script as `http://localhost/[directory name]/[file name].php`

Ok, you can do it now. Fine, if your browser shows well on `http://localhost`, then run `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` (i assume that you have phpmyadmin installed and configured properly for mysql- if not, consider installing it). Can you login and see the localhost interface of mysql?

If you can see nothing, [restart apache](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/).