# PHP errors are not showing in browser only page goes blank

Tags: mysql, php

I'm learning to set up my LAMP server. I'm in a stage where I'm trying to connect MySQL to PHP files. It's kinda hard to work out where the problem is considering that all I'm getting is a blank page. No error lines, nothing.

here's my block of code:

```
<?php
//connect to mysql

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','vengaboys','shoutit');

//test the connection

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo 'failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
ini_set('display_errors', 'shoutit');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050426/php-errors-not-being-displayed-in-the-browser-ubuntu-10-10) to enable display errors in php.

Comment: This is really a programming question that would be better on [SO].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, display errors in PHP are **OFF**. You have to turn it **ON** Manually.

Locate the following files.

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Now find `display_errors` in that page. It must be Off. You have to change it and make it `On`.

Now restart the server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

An error will display instead of a blank page.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you ! Now I can see the error line. Apparently there's something wrong with my login. It says "failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Now I know what to go after .... cheers !

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Have fun!! :)